Vsftpd: how to hide version?
I have tried with a old unix client (on Interactive Unix)
the command "remotestatus" and on my ftp server (vsftpd)
show the version!
ftp> remotestatus
ftp> 211-FTP server status:
     Connected to ???
     Logged in as ftp
     TYPE: BINARY
     No session bandwidth limit
     Session timeout in seconds is 300
     Control connection is plain text
     Data connections will be plain text
     vsFTPd 3.0.3 - secure, fast, stable

Is possible to hide the version? Change the banner don't work.

From vsftp's postlogin.c, in the handling of the STAT request (which seems to be what your client does when you type in remotestatus):
  vsf_cmdio_write_raw(p_sess,
    "     vsFTPd " VSF_VERSION " - secure, fast, stable\r\n");
  vsf_cmdio_write(p_sess, FTP_STATOK, "End of status");

In other words, that string containing the version is a compile-time constant.
You need to patch postlogin.c to not include the version in that string, rebuild your vsftp (probably using the operating system tooling for your server to not mess up security), and re-deploy it.
Or, and this is clearly the better option, not do that and live with the fact that clients can trivially figure out the version of your server. Seriously, what do you think you can hide? You're using probably the most popular FTP server on earth, the thing hasn't seen a release since 2021, the one before (yours) is from 2015, so realistically, if I need to figure out what version your server is, I need to read like four diffs of postlogin.c to figure out what I need to ask for to functionally figure out your server's version, without it ever telling me the version number. Or even easier, read the Changelog file. If your server responds without a trailing period to EPSV, it's newer than 3.0.2, and if it closes the connection after 10 unknown commands pre-login, it's < 3.0.4. That was easy.

Vsftpd: how to hide version?

So, basically, not at all. It's trivial to figure out figure out the version of vsftpd based on its behavior, you can't hide that behavior from the client, because it's what vsftpd is.

Where did you get your version of vsftpd from? Mine, version 3.0.5 complains about that command:
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
230 Login successful.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp> remotestatus
?Invalid command

The banner change does what I expect...
vsftd.conf
# You may fully customise the login banner string:
ftpd_banner=Welcome to blah FTP service.
#
"./vsftpd.conf" 155L, 5849C

And then connecting to it:
$ ftp w.x.y.z
Connected to localhost.
220 Welcome to blah FTP service.

P.S.: I just checked the source code - the word remotestatus doesn't feature in it?

I think "remotestatus" is just a client-side thing, and sends the RFC 959 STAT command to the server.

Remotestatus is a client command of ftp client of Interactive Unix 4.1.1
